# Benefits of using spring data flow over spring batching

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am working on evaluating the technologies we are using for processing the data of a large file and writing it to the database.

I need to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of using the  using **spring data flow** over **spring batch** in terms of handling large files very fast without increasing memory and without breaking them to batches and picking up pause process

I need to know which technology is better

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Dataflow are not at the same level of abstraction to be compared to each other.

Spring Batch is a batch processing framework that provides features to create and run batch jobs. Spring Cloud Dataflow on the other hand is a tool that allows you to run streaming and ephemeral apps, including, but not limited to Spring Batch jobs. What SCDF brings to the table compared to using only Spring Batch is the ability to:

- Run, stop, restart batch jobs from a Web UI, the CLI and an API
- Inspect job logs from the Web UI
- Inspect job metrics and tracing from the Web UI
- Compose batch jobs into composed tasks to create advanced workflows
- Upgrade/Downgrade batch applications in a seamless, production grade way
- And many [other features](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/)

So it is not an "either or" question or "which is better", those are complementary tools that you can use in combination to deploy a modern batch infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What do you mean exactly by Upgrade/Downgrade batch applications in a seamless, production grade way?

Comment: I mean the spring cloud skipper way of doing this through the `upgrade`/`rollback` commands (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/docs/2.8.6/reference/htmlsingle/#skipper-commands-release-upgrade), compared to SSHing in production and copying/replacing jars (or sometimes even overriding class files in an exploded `war` directory.. true story).